# Sonar Implementation error through ant

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube

I have the following code from my ant file

```
<property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://sonar.ip.tdk.dk/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"/>
```

An error is coming  The reference to entity `&characterEncoding&quot;` must end with the ';' delimiter.

Can anyone help with this

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `&` in the JDBC URL as `&amp;`. Failing to do so results in an invalid `build.xml`.